# What are the least invasive permissions required to toggle Airplane Mode?

Tags: android

In Android, what are the permissions for toggling Airplane Mode? Can I do it without the "Modify global system settings" (WRITE_SETTINGS) permission?

As a developer, I want to make my app use the least invasive permissions so that permission-aware security-conscious people can be satisfied with my app and know I'm not doing something fishy with their data behind the scenes or messing their phone settings up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way around the WRITE_SETTINGS permission is to ask the user to change the setting manually by launching the settings activity:

```
startActivityForResult(
        new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, prompting the user would defeat the purpose of making an app similar to Siri. It'd be nice if they had more specific permissions, or if Airplane Mode was included in the "modify network settings".